# How can I set bits of a vector from different processes or modules?

Tags: vhdl

I'm adding an error vector to my design. It is a collection of error bits from all over the large design.

Now, I could route each error bit from the module that originates it all the way up to the top and connect it to its spot in the error vector at the top. However, as I add or remove or change error bits, that will result in a lot of places that I need to update port declarations and be a pain in the neck to maintain.

I would much rather pass the entire error vector all around my design, and have each place where an error originates just update its spot in the error vector. Is there any way to do that in VHDL?

There's nothing wrong with this from a hardware standpoint - each bit of the vector is only being driven in one place.

To illustrate the issue, here is an example of the first way of doing it:

```
entity moduleB is
  port (
    moduleB_error : out std_logic
  )
end moduleB;
architecture rtl of moduleB is
  moduleB_error <= '1';
begin
end rtl;

entity moduleC is
  port (
    moduleC_error : out std_logic
  )
end moduleC;
architecture rtl of moduleC is
  moduleC_error <= '1';
begin
end rtl;

entity moduleA is
  port (
    moduleB_error : out std_logic
  )
end moduleA;
architecture rtl of moduleA is
  signal moduleB_error : std_logic;
begin
  inst_moduleB : entity work.moduleB
    port map(
      moduleB_error => moduleB_error
    );
end rtl;

entity top is
  port (
    error_vector : out std_logic_vector(255 downto 0)
  );
end top;
architecture rtl of top is
  signal moduleB_error : std_logic;
  signal moduleC_error : std_logic;

  error_vector(0) <= moduleB_error;
  error_vector(1) <= moduleC_error;
begin
  inst_moduleA : entity work.moduleA
    port map(
      moduleB_error => moduleB_error
    );
  inst_moduleC : entity work.moduleC
    port map(
      moduleC_error => moduleC_error
    );
end rtl;
```

I would much rather do something like this:

```
entity moduleB is
  port (
    error_vector    : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
  )
end moduleB;
architecture rtl of moduleB is
  error_vector(0)  <= '1';
begin
end rtl;

entity moduleC is
  port (
    error_vector    : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
  )
end moduleC;
architecture rtl of moduleC is
  error_vector(1)    <= '1';
begin
end rtl;

entity moduleA is
  port (
    error_vector : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  )
end moduleA;
architecture rtl of moduleA is
begin
  inst_moduleB : entity work.moduleB
    port map(
      error_vector => error_vector
    );
end rtl;

entity top is
  port (
    error_vector : out std_logic_vector(255 downto 0)
  );
end top;
architecture rtl of top is
begin
  inst_moduleA : entity work.moduleA
    port map(
      error_vector => error_vector    -- PROBLEM - multiple drivers for error_vector
    );
  inst_moduleC : entity work.moduleC
    port map(
      error_vector => error_vector    -- PROBLEM - multiple drivers for error_vector
    );
end rtl;
```

Comment: For the second set of snippets adding missing context clauses, semicolons to the entity declarations, moving the architecture body begins below the assignments, removing the semicolon at the end of the interface list in moduleA and we see the actual constraints don't match the formal ones for inst_ModuleA and inst_ModuleC. Your purported synthesis issue doesn't match the VHDL elaboration error.  A formal and an actual are required to have matching elements. If Module A & C's formal's were full length you'd find with *longest static prefix* they'd write different bits and that should work.

Comment: And you could demonstrate that by eliminating the context clauses, changing all std_logic_vector mentions to bit_vector, fixing the begin s and semicolons, analyzing, elaborating and simulating - element type bit is not a resolved type and may not have multiple drivers. A process has a driver for each element of the longest static prefix (IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers,  8. Names, 8.1). Both can have ports of the longer name but if they do not drive the same elements there is no multiple driver. So now the problem is how do you tell what instantiated 'Modules' to drive which bits?

Comment: You could note your two sets of snippets are roughly equivalent, differing by where which error_vector bit is driven by which 'Module'.  (You could do that with generics, whereupon the information still shows up in top.)

Comment: There are no explicit processes in your code. The error you're getting for solution two is a multiple source error.

Comment: 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements *A concurrent signal assignment statement represents an equivalent process statement that assigns values to signals.*  [second snippet corrected for  analysis](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sed5lzxktz0jx7r/top.vhdl?dl=1) produces errors 'actual constraints don't match formal ones' and [second snippet with error_vector length 256 and bit_vector types](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4gxv63k06u5hinn/top1.vhdl?dl=0) which analyzes, elaborates and simulates (and will synthesize whereupon the the unused error_vector out port elements will be removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can map bits to parts of an vector:

```
entity moduleA is
  port (
    error_vector    : out std_logic
  );
end entity;

entity moduleB is
  port (
    error_vector    : out std_logic
  );
end entity;


entity top is
  port (
    error_vector : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
  );
end entity;

architecture rtl of top is
begin
  A : entity work.moduleA
    port map(
      error_vector => error_vector(0)
    );
  B : entity work.moduleB
    port map(
      error_vector => error_vector(1)
    );

end architecture rtl;
```

No multiple source problem will be created.